# Duplicates of unanswered questions - why flagging them is not allowed?

Tags: discussion

Currently it's impossible to flag a question as a duplicate, if that older question has no upvoted or accepted answer.

"This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer" error is shown.

Does it mean it's all right to repost question until it's answered (or, more accurately, until person who asks likes the answer)? If not, why is this restriction in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the rationale behind this is that *if* the older question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer, it is not ([as defined by SO/SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate)) really answered.  So if the question is asked at a later date, by a *different* user, and usually with a different angle of attack, then it should not be closed as a duplicate, but instead given a new chance on the front page.  And since it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate (since there is no good answer), flagging such a question as a duplicate would just be noise.  Hence no encouragement to flag as a duplicate.

> Does it mean it's all right to repost question until it's answered (or, more accurately, until person who asks likes the answer)? If not, why is this restriction in place?

Of course not!  You can still flag for moderator's *attention*.  That would be the cause of action when there is obvious abuse (as in the example you give). But you should not ask for moderators' (or anyone elses's) attention by *flagging* if there is just two *different* users who asks a similiar questions independent of each other, and no *good* answer to either question has been acknowledged (by acceptance or upvoting).

But if you think the answer to the older question is a good one, then *you* should upvote it (if you're not the person who wrote it). And *then* you can flag the new question as a duplicate.

Of course, if you're the person who answered the old question, you're not allowed to upvote yourself.  In that case, I suggest that you post a comment with a link pointing back to your old answer.  If it is as great as you think, the new attention will most likely get it upvoted.   *Then* you can flag the new question as a duplicate.

And if it is still not upvoted, it was probably not such a great answer after all, and it is fair to let the new question have its time - unclosed - on the front page.

As long as both questions remain open, they may of course both aquire a tail of excellent and upvoted answers.  I don't think this scenario is very likely, but if it does happen, it need not be a waste since moderators are permitted to *merge* questions. So if a moderator discovers that there are two near identical questions and that both now have good answers, they can merge all the good answers below the clearest written question, and close the other.

In balance, I think the advantages of not being allowed to flag a question as a duplicate if there are no upvoted or accepted answer outweight the disadvantages.

Comment: But then if older question will ever be "answered", new one may get closed as a duplicate, right? Even if new one is answered too. Seems like a chance for wasted efforts.

Answer (score 1):

No, duplicating a question is not something users should do; that is true whenever the previous answer was written by the same user or from a different user.

The restriction has been implemented because pointing the future users to a question with answers is thought to be more useful than pointing the users to another question without answers. This is particularly important for anonymous users who are automatically redirected from a question that is closed as duplicate to the duplicated question; this means that if a question with an answer is closed as duplicate of a question without answers, the anonymous users (coming from Google, for example) will never see that answer.

The restriction changes the way questions are closed as duplicate; it does make writing the same question over and over acceptable. For example:

- Instead of closing a question as duplicate of a question that is not constructive, not a real question, or off-topic without answers, close it as not constructive, not a real question, or off-topic
- Instead of closing a newer question with answers as duplicate of a older question without answers, close the older question as duplicate of the newer question.

In all this, voting doesn't matter. The purpose is not "I redirect you to a question with answers so you can vote them," but "I redirect you to a question with answers so you can find the answer you were looking for." In fact, the most penalized users (the ones without an account, who are automatically redirected to the duplicated question) are also the ones who cannot vote posts.

It is then still possible to close a question as duplicate, when the other question has up-voted answers. Up-voted answers are a signal that there are users who checked the answer was not utterly wrong, and that can be considered as a *quality* signal.

Clearly, if you see a user asking the same question (even with different words), flag one of the questions for moderation attention. The users should be reminded that, instead of creating a slightly different question, they can edit their own question to add details, or make it clearer.

See [Changes to "close as duplicate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate) and the comments written there to understand how the system for closing questions will be eventually changed.